# Fast way to import 24000 single variation products to Shopify

Tags: ruby, api, rest, shopify

I want to import ~24000 (single variation) products to Shopify every night at 04:00.

The problem with the default `Admin > Products > Import > CSV` method is that it takes an unacceptably long time to finish. So I started working with the [Shopify API](http://docs.shopify.com/api/product) using their [Ruby gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api).

The Shopify API has an API call limit of 2 calls per second, with room for a burst of 40 calls at once. You can read more about the API call limit [here](http://docs.shopify.com/api/introduction/api-call-limit). I don't understand the "room for a burst of 40 calls at once" part.

A Shopify Employee told me the following about importing products via the API:

> If you were to make Product creation API requests that includes the
>   variant information in them (assuming 3 variants per product) and
>   using a default API limit (refresh of 2 requests per second, or 2
>   concurrent requests) you could probably finish creating all those
>   products in about 67 minutes.

I wrote the following Ruby script to import all products to Shopify:

```
require 'shopify_api'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

begin_time = Time.now

shop_url  = "https://<API_KEY>:<PASSWORD>@<SHOPNAME>.myshopify.com/admin"

ShopifyAPI::Base.site = shop_url

raw_product_data = JSON.parse(open('<LINK>') {|f| f.read }.force_encoding('UTF-8'))
raw_product_data_size = raw_product_data.size

puts '========================================================================='
puts "#{raw_product_data_size} products loaded. Starting import now..."
puts '-------------------------------------------------------------------------'

raw_product_data.each_with_index do |item, index|
  single_product_begin_time = Time.now

  # Store item data in variables
  <DATA>

  # Create new product
  new_product = ShopifyAPI::Product.new
  new_product.title = title
  new_product.body_html = body
  new_product.product_type = type
  new_product.vendor = vendor
  new_product.tags = tags

  new_product.variants = [
    {
      "option_1" => "First",
      "price" => variant_price,
      "sku" => variant_sku
    }
  ]

  new_product.images = [
    {
      src: image_src
    }
  ]

  new_product.save

  creation_time = Time.now - single_product_begin_time

  puts "#{((index / raw_product_data_size.to_f) * 100).round(2)}% - #{index} - #{variant_sku} added in #{creation_time.round(2)} seconds"
end

puts '-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
puts "Done. It took #{begin_time - Time.now} minutes."
puts '========================================================================='
```

But I'm not getting anywhere near the 67 minutes.

It currently takes around 3 seconds to add a single product. At this rate it would take 20 hours to add 24000 products. That's unacceptable. Everything under 2 hours is acceptable.

What could I try to speed things up?

Comment: Its probably because they host the API on the same servers as the regular web app, which is dog slow and probably oversold * 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and sweet answer, use multithreading.

Since a single product took ~3 seconds to import, my solution is having 5 workers (threads) running the product import and checking for 429 errors. If they hit a 429, they pause for 10 seconds and then retry. It currently takes ~3,6 hours to import ~26000 product.

Answer (score 0):

Another option here is avoiding throttling requests until you start hitting rate limit errors from shopify. This ensures that you are taking advantage of the burst limits and only pausing when the Shopify API is rate limiting you.

I wrote a gem which handles detecting the `429` error (and other network errors) and automatically retrying based on an exponential backoff schedule.

https://github.com/iloveitaly/shopify_api_extensions/

I believe Shopify also has the option of increasing your rate limit. Contact their support to see if they can raise the limits on your account.